# The following notification pops up when my bash script isn't opened or focused: No code found or selected

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

How do I resolve this?

I read the documentation of the extension and it doesn't say anything about the extension running without having the code file focused.

The following is my current `settings.json` file and I don't know how to make the extension run without having to have my bash script open.

```
{
    "runOnSave.commands": [{
        "match": ".*",
        "command": "code-runner.run",
                "runIn": "vscode" 
        "runningStatusMessage": "Running ${fileBasename}.",
        "finishStatusMessage": "${fileBasename} completed."


    }],
    "runOnSave.statusMessageTimeout": 78000,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
    "code-runner.cwd": "/location/to/bash/script",
    "code-runner.defaultLanguage": "BASH/SH",
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true,
    "code-runner.customCommand": "./bash-script.sh"
}
```

[Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.run-on-save)

If there is no solution then is there another extension that will let me run a command? And if the extension tries to run the code again, it will fail and say something like: "Command already running." The extension won't run the command again until the command finished, sadly I have been looking all over the Vscode Marketplace for something like this and I have only found this `code-runner` extension that does what I want precisely. Except for the part that I need to have a code-file open to run the extension.

E.g.

$NAME-OF-EXTENSION runs the following command to run a `bash-script`:

`./time.sh`

Which contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

  echo "time"
  sleep 10
  echo "time"
  sleep 10
  echo "time"
  sleep 10
  echo "time"
```

If the $NAME-OF-EXTENSION runs command again, then it won't start the command and instead a notification in Vscode will pop-up saying, "Command already running."
Only one time the notification will pop-up, then when the `bash-script` is running and also after it's done, an output will appear.

An example of how the `Output` will look like is like the following that `code-runner` contains:

```
[Running] bash "./time.sh"
  time
  time
  time
  time

[Done] exited with code=127 in 31.4 seconds
```

Comment: use the shell command `time` with custom report string, you can use tasks for this

Comment: Why do you want to run the script from your IDE specifically? Just run it in a terminal instead.

Comment: @tripleee I don't want the terminal to show when the command is running, I only want it to be in the `Output`. 

@rioV8 Will tasks also have the ability to not re-run the same task until it's done?

Comment: Possible to just run the Vscode `task` silently so the terminal won't pop-up like the following extension has.
[Run on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.run-on-save)
?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out that I can just run the custom command of `Code-Runner`.

Which then I created the following solution with two other Extensions.

[multi-Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)
&
[Save and Run Ext](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=padjon.save-and-run-ext)
with [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

The following `settings.json` file contains the configuration(s) of each extension.

```
{
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,                                            // Auto save delay. ( In Milliseconds.)   
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": true,                              // Shows [Running] $FILE -&- [Done] $ARG $TIME seconds.
    "code-runner.customCommand": "/Location/To/File/Git-Automations.sh",  // Code-Runner customCommand that runs the Bash/Script.
    "code-runner.preserveFocus": false,                                  // To preserve focus on code editor after code run is triggered.

    "multiCommand.commands": [{                 
        "command": "closePanel",             // Name of the command.
        "interval": 30,                     // In milliseconds.
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.closePanel" // Closes terminal/panel.
        ]
    }],
    "saveAndRunExt": {

        "commands": [{
                "match": "/Location/To/All/Github/Repositories*",      // Location where Github-Repositories are at.
                "isShellCommand": false,                              // If false, Vscode commands are then ran.
                "cmd": "code-runner.runCustomCommand"                // Runs Code-Runner customCommand.
            },
            {
                "match": "/Location/To/All/Github/Repositories*", // Location where Github-Repositories are at.
                "isShellCommand": false,                         // If false, Vscode commands are then ran.
                "cmd": "closePanel"                             // Closes the terminal/panel.
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Everytime a file saves, the commands will be run.